# Docker not showing logs written in /dev/stdout

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I started some docker containers with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

(here the [docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/pensiero/e4237d21e27d60ac6394f4d66285149e))

and then:

```
docker-compose logs -f web
```

but if I write on another shell:

```
docker-compose exec web echo "hello" >> /dev/stdout
```

Nothing appear in the live logs screen.
Same for any other container. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`/dev/stdout` is different for each process. Your `docker-compose logs` will only show you the output of your PID 1 process, not other processes that run in that container namespace.

Update:  also note:

- `>> /dev/stdout` will be applying to `docker compose exec web echo "hello"` on the host .. not to `echo "hello"` inside the container
- `>> /dev/stdout` is kind of a no-op because a process will write to stdout by default .. and, for stdout, `>>` (append) is the same as `>` (redirect) because there's no pre-existing output that can be overwritten/replaced.

Comment: So what should I have to do to log and read via `docker-compose logs`? Thanks

Comment: I _hate_ to be beaten, but ... I'm going to say you can't do that. If you can find a way to do it, then it's really the sort of ugly hack that you probably shouldn't be doing.  If I were you, then I'd be asking myself why I wanted to achieve this, and whether there's some alternative solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved putting this inside the virtualhost configuration:

```
CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 combined
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
```

So, in order to show up logs on docker, you can use `/proc/self/fd/1` and `/proc/self/fd/2`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the way I deal with it is this:

```
# file /etc/apache2/sites-available/XXXXXXX.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ErrorLog /proc/1/fd/2
    CustomLog /proc/1/fd/1 combined
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```